# How to properly implement a helper function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, syntax-error

**The 'gridList' function description:**

Takes two `Integer` inputs, 
`x` and `y`, and returns a list of tuples representing the coordinates
of each cell from `(1,1)` to `(x,y)`.

**Example Output**

```
$> gridList 3 3
$> [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

**Source Code**

```
gridList :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer,Integer)]
gridList 1 1 = [(1,1)]
gridList 1 y = helper 1 y
gridList x y = (helper x y) ++ gridList (x-1) y
  where 
    helper :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
    helper x 1 = [(x,1)]
    helper x y = (x,y) : (helper x (y-1))
```

**Question:** The code doesn't compile giving the following `error: Variable not in scope`
referring to the line 3 where the helper is first introduced. Why doesn't the `where`solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The scope of a `where` is just the single definition (equals sign) above it.  You need to either pull the helper out of the where, or convert the main gridList patterns into another helper.

Comment: Side note: you'll likely want to rework your algorithm, as this `gridList` won't produce the pairs in the order you expect.

Comment: The easiest way to implement this function is probably with a list comprehension. You can define it in a single line, which will be easily comprehensible to anyone familiar with the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, `where`-bound definitions are in scope only in the equation immediately above the `where` block. This means that if you define a function using multiple equations, each of them gets a separate `where` block.

In your case, the definition of `helper` is in scope only for the third equation (line 4), but not for the first two.

In order to use the same `helper` definition for all branches, change the definition from three separate equations to a `case` expression:

```
gridList :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer,Integer)]
gridList x y = case (x, y) of
    (1, 1) -> [(1,1)]
    (1, _) -> helper 1 y
    _ -> (helper x y) ++ gridList (x-1) y
  where 
    helper :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
    helper x 1 = [(x,1)]
    helper x y = (x,y) : (helper x (y-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer! makes perfect sense now

Comment: As an aside, this answer has some extraneous parentheses I think it'd be better style to remove: both uses of `helper` don't need parens.

Comment: It's a conscious choice @amalloy: I try to minimize changes to the OP's code besides those necessary to answer the question. This way there is less chance of confusion.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you'd copied those sections directly. I agree, good decision to leave the parens alone.

Comment: However, the output isn't the same as the example which starts from (1,1). I've tried to replace```++``` with ```:``` raising an error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the scope of the where-clause covers only the last equation. I'd usually suggest using a case-expression instead of multiple equations. However, since you are doing pattern matches on two arguments, doing that here requires either matching on a pair, as in [Fyodor Soikin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60960953/2751851), or nested case-expressions:

```
gridList :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer,Integer)]
gridList x y = case x of
    1 -> case y of
        1 -> [(1,1)]
        _ -> helper 1 y
    _ -> helper x y ++ gridList (x-1) y
    where 
    helper :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
    helper x 1 = [(x,1)]
    helper x y = (x,y) : helper x (y-1)
```

The least invasive workaround is probably using pattern guards:

```
gridList :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer,Integer)]
gridList x y
    | 1 <- x, 1 <- y = [(1,1)]
    | 1 <- x = helper 1 y
    | otherwise = helper x y ++ gridList (x-1) y
    where
    helper :: Integer -> Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
    helper x 1 = [(x,1)]
    helper x y = (x,y) : helper x (y-1)
```

[As luqui suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960469/how-to-properly-implement-a-helper-function-in-haskell#comment107851336_60960469), other options include pulling `helper` out of the where-clause, and pushing the equations inside it (`gridList = go where go 1 1 = [(1,1)]  -- etc.`).

Comment: Oh interesting I hadn't considered replacing patterns with pattern guards to solve this sort of pattern